# How can I bind a generic Value to a Child Component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Generic Blazor Component CustomInputForm which takes an Enumerable of TItems, each TItem has an Child how can i pass the Bind-value(int) to the CustomRadioGroup so that changes will be reflected in the Parrent?

CustomInputForm:

```
@typeparam TItem
@typeparam TChild
<EditForm Model="Data">
    @foreach (var item in Data)
    {
        <CustomRadioGroup Data="@GetChild(item)"></CustomRadioGroup>
    }
</EditForm>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Func<TItem, TChild> GetChild { get; set; }
}
```

CustomRadioGroup

```
@typeparam TValue
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="???">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <InputRadio class="form-check-input radio-input" Value="i">@i</InputRadio>
        <Label class="form-check-label">@i</Label>
    }
</InputRadioGroup>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TValue Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding generic constrain to the type param will solve your problem.
You can add constaint like:

```
@typeparam TValue where TValue : ISomeInterface
```

Define the required properties in the interface (or a base class). After that you can access the properties in the component.

```
public interface ISomeInterface 
{
   int Field { get; set; }
}
```

```
@typeparam TValue ISomeInterface
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="Data.Field">

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TValue Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is an option. But my goal is to make the component independent of a certain type.